# Scala Option apply method when passed a None

Tags: design, scala, implementations

Not sure if this is an appropriate question for here, please let me know!

In Scala, the ever so useful [`Option`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html) class has an [`apply`](https://github.com/othiym23/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L22) method in its companion object that allows us to quickly wrap any value into an `Option`:

```scala
def apply[A](x: A): Option[A] = if (x == null) None else Some(x)
```

This is super helpful when dealing with mixed Java/Scala code. As you can wrap `null` in an `Option` and get back a Scala friendly `None`. However, if you do `Option(None)` you receive a `Some(None)`, when perhaps you would expect to receive a `None` back.

My question is why wasn't the design of that method something more like:

```scala
def apply[A](x: A): Option[A] = if (x == null || x == None) None else Some(x)
```

Does `Some(None)` make more sense in some scenarios? I would like the second approach to do something like:

```scala
val isNull = Option(someValue).isEmpty // returns false for Some(None)
```

Comment: `Option()` is applied to nullable values. Are you saying that you are passing in a nullable `Option` value? If so, rethink your coding practices.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the apply method was designed to create an option from a nullable value, and if you already have an `Option`, there's not really a need to create one.  Also a `Some(None)` is valid in certain circumstances where you already have an `Option` and you want to call a method on its contents that also returns an `Option`, although you would generally use a `flatMap` or quickly call `flatten` afterward to avoid having that confusing situation for very long.

Answer (score 0):

An option has 2 possible values at a high level, some or none.

Some(None) seems to be an option in an option